# Selenium and the invisible element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

ElementClickInterceptedException exception indicates that the element I'm trying to click on is intercepted by another element that overlaps it and does not allow the click. it appears that an  element with an ID of “lku5h” is overlapping the button I'm trying to click but the ID of the  element changes every time I access the page. I have tried to wait for the element to disappear, but the elements are not always the same . How to click on the blue button "Click to continue" ?

```
Class Website():

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def get_click(self):
    self.driver.get("https://stayonline.pro/l/QNZqJ/")

    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Click to continue")]')))

    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'lk2t')))
    click_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,   '//button[contains(text(),"Click to continue")]')
    click_button.click()

website = Website()
website.get_click()
```

> Error message :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element 

click intercepted: Element <button type="button" class="btnClickToContinueLink btn 

btn-primary btn-block shadow text-center btn-lg  mb-1">...</button> is not clickable 

at point (1100, 128). Other element would receive the click: <a id="lkxzc" 

href="http://nancontrast.com/x0spmhcctv?fapsxi=68&amp;refer=https%3A%2F


%2Fstayonline.pro%2Fl%2FQNZqJ%2F&amp;kw=%5B%22l%22%2C%22elefante%22%2C%22del%22%2C

%22mago%22%2C%222023%22%2C%22webrip%22%2C%22ac3%22%2C%22ita%22%2C%22cb01%22%2C   %22avi

%22%2C%22maxstream%22%2C%22video%22%2C%22stayonline%22%2C%22pro

%22%5D&amp;key=8b5cfe59b68dbbe6ccd383dac495922e&amp;scrWidth=1440&amp;scrHeight=900&

amp;tz=2&amp;v=22.10.v.9&amp;ship=&amp;sub3=invoke_layer&amp;res=14.31&amp;dev=r&

amp;uuid=b38e1c78-9e02-45f3-b223-ae79ef03c988%3A1%3A1" target="_blank" 

style="display: block; height: inherit;"></a>
```